# CSS 3 Column Divs loop

Tags: css, drupal, html

I have a drupal view which pulls out project screen shots and puts them into divs, and I was wondering if there was a clever way in CSS to align them in a row of 3 columns with a margin without styling each box individually.

First row styles easily, because i can give div-even a left and right margin, but then row 2 i need to give the div-odd a margin and the even div no margin

I have created a J fiddle Mockup of where I am at. I can style the class of the first and last div and also give a rule to odd and even, but because i don't know how project screen shots their will be I'd prefer not to style each div box individually

http://jsfiddle.net/eGWY6/

Comment: Can you give some indication of how you want the resulting HTML to look? A graphic would be fine, with some explanation of the rules you want to apply to the odd, and even, classes.

Comment: you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/eGWY6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this this way:

jQuery:

```
// Remove margin on third project screen shot
if($("#projects-wrapper div").length){
  $("#projects-wrapper div").each(function(i){
    var remainder = (i + 1) % 3; //3th change to your needs
    if(remainder === 0){
      $(this).addClass("last");
    }
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
.last {margin-right: 0;}
```

Comment: While this may be the necessary approach, it's worth mentioning the complete absence (certainly as of writing) of any mention of the [tag:jquery] tag.

Comment: its Drupal, its included by default

Comment: Thanks so much this did the trick, took me ages to get it to work, because I didn't realise about behaviors in drupal 7!

Answer (score 0):

Hey now define css as like this

```
.view-last{
margin-right:0;
}
.view-4{
margin-left:0;
}
```

***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eGWY6/3/)***

Answer (score 0):

CHeck out this fiddle I think this is what you are looking for.. If you give width in percentages then it will be easy to place them.

http://jsfiddle.net/eGWY6/7/

Now you can name the alternate divs with odd or even and style them.. As simple as that